# How to test webserver performance with Visual Studio 2010 Load Test Tools

Tags: visual-studio-2010, load-testing

I'm currently looking at trying to use VS2010 Ultimate for Load Testing purposes and I know how this works. I want to be able to see what the server load on the remote webserver is when the tests are being performed but I cannot see any information on what I need to install to do this test is

If anyone has any information or has any experience in this area it would be very useful

thanks

paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the servers you want into the "Counter set" when you use the "new load test wizard".

By this uses the Perfmon counters on windows servers to give you feedback on all the items you want to see.

There are some firewall/security issues around opening the [ports for remote performance monitoring](https://serverfault.com/questions/37942/use-perfmon-to-connect-to-a-remote-computer).

Answer (score 0):

I found out where the issue was - by default the webtest doesnt use the default proxy details that come with IE

therefore in the properties of the webtest you need to type the word 'default' into the proxy value

seems like a bit of a weird thing to happen!